# Conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, where-clause

Question is simple - I believe answer may be simple too.

System is SQL Server 2008 R2.

There  is a stored procedure `sp_WHYWHYWHY` which takes 3 parameters - 2 are dates and one is supplier code.

The `WHERE` clause in the statement looks something like this:

```
OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND SupplierCode = @SupplierCode
```

The business process has changed - as it always will. So now in the supplier code there is only one supplier (let's say `YY`)who is now aligned, business-wise, to another supplier (let's say `ABC`).

Hence the code needs to say when querying for `ABC` - include `YY` as well.

Something like

```
OrderDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND SupplierCode = CASE WHEN @SupplierCode = 'ABC' THEN 'YY','ABC' ELSE @SupplierCode END
```

I know you can't write this like that - but that's just what the end result should be.

How can I do this, really?

Thanks for taking out time to read & answer.

Comment: Do you have a table where you keep track of supplierCodes which reference the alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overthink it! You want the supplier code to match the provided value, *or* the provided value to be `ABC` and the stored supplier code to be `YY`.

Try this

```
AND ([SupplierCode] = @SupplierCode
OR ([SupplierCode] <> @SupplierCode 
    AND @SupplierCode ='ABC' 
    AND [SupplierCode] = 'YY'))
```

Comment: The disjunction must be enclosed in brackets for this to work as expected.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst But that will bring ABC & YY irrespective. I mean if the user Sends on XYZ, this code will show XYZ as well as ABC & YY. I want it to eveluate passed value. And if the passed value is ABC then include YY. Else use the passed value. So even if the passed value is YY it should only show YY. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @CeeVei thanks for the explanation; I think you are saying the things are AndriyM. I've updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: You haven't enclosed the entire disjunction in brackets, though. I mean, it should be `AND ([SupplierCode] = @SupplierCode
OR ...)`, so that the entire filter would look like this: `condition1 AND (condition2a OR condition2b)`. `OR` has lower priority than `AND` in SQL Server and *must* be bracketed in this case.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Kirk's piece of code make sense. Andriy - i missed your comment initially. Thanks Kirk